# Remove lines contains specific number of words

Tags: php

My question can be understood with an example given below :

Suppose This is the text file, which contains these lines :

> hello this is my word file and this is line number 1
>   hello this is second line and this is some text
>   hello this is third line and again some text
>   jhasg djgha sdgasjhgdjasgh jdkh
>   sdhgfkjg sdjhgf sjkdghf sdhf
>   s hdg fjhsgd fjhgsdj gfj ksdgh

- I want to get each line into a variable

  then get all the words of that line into an array

  then compare that array which contains words of that line WITH all the   words of next lines

  if the number of matches of words is more than 3 that line is deleted

so in the above example the output should be :

> hello this is my word file and this is line number 1
>   jhasg djgha sdgasjhgdjasgh jdkh
>   sdhgfkjg sdjhgf sjkdghf sdhf
>   s hdg fjhsgd fjhgsdj gfj ksdgh

Because `hello this is line` is more than 3 words, so the lines containing those words are deleted. Please note that the first line is not deleted because it is unique....

I tried to code myself and created a mess which created 200mb text file with the unlimited number of first line text. Anyways here is the code, dont execute it else you can end up having your hard disk full.

```
<?php

$fileA = fopen("names.txt", "r");
$fileB = fopen("anothernames.txt", "r");
$fileC = fopen("uniquenames.txt", "w");
while(!feof($fileA))
{
    $line = fgets($fileA);
    $words = explode(" ", $line);
    $size = count($words);

    while(!feof($fileA))
    {
        $line1 = fgets($fileB);
        $words1 = explode(" ", $line1);
        $size1 = count($words1);

        $c=0;

        for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
        {
                for($j=0; $j<$size1; $j++)
            {
                    if($words[$i]==$words1[$j])
                        $c++;
            }
        }
        if($c<3)
            fwrite($fileC, $line);
    }
}

fclose($fileA);
fclose($fileB);
fclose($fileC);

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: When comparing line 1 `hello this is my word file and this is line number 1` to line 2 `hello this is second line and this is some text` you want to delete both lines because there are more than 3 occurrences of the same word, is that correct? Is line 3 then being compared to the previous line 2 (which was deleted) or line 4; or are the common words all stored and any future lines with them should be delete?

Comment: You got my point bro, I want to compare the words of line 1 to all the lines and then compare the words of line 2 to all the next below lines and this goes on... But also i dont want to delete that unique line in which those words appear 1 time (means i want to keep that line which appear only 1 time and that line is unique).... so output should also include the first line, i have to edit my post please check the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach would be the following:

- read all the lines, using `file()`
- create an array, containing the sentence, indexed by each word.
- finally build a blacklist of every sentence which appears in any of the arrays, counting more than 3 entries for any word.
- Then print every line, except the blacklisted:

Example:

```
    <?php
$lines = array("hello this is my word file and this is line number 1",
  "hello this is second line and this is some text",
  "hello this is third line and again some text",
  "jhasg djgha sdgasjhgdjasgh jdkh",
  "sdhgfkjg sdjhgf sjkdghf sdhf",
  "s hdg fjhsgd fjhgsdj gfj ksdgh");

//$lines = file("path/to/file");

$result = array();
//build "count-per-word" array
foreach ($lines AS $line){
   $words = explode(" ", $line);
   foreach ($words AS $word){
       $word = strtolower($word);
       if (isset($result[$word]))
           $result[$word][] = $line;
       else
           $result[$word] = array($line);  
   }
}

//Blacklist each sentence, containing a word appearing in 3 sentences.
$blacklist = array();
foreach ($result AS $word => $entries){
   if (count($entries) >= 3){
     foreach($entries AS $entry){
       $blacklist[] = $entry;
     }
   }
}

//list all not blacklisted. 
foreach ($lines AS $line){
  if (!in_array($line, $blacklist))
      echo $line."<br />";
}

?>
```

Output:

```
jhasg djgha sdgasjhgdjasgh jdkh
sdhgfkjg sdjhgf sjkdghf sdhf
s hdg fjhsgd fjhgsdj gfj ksdgh
```

Note, that this will also blacklist a single sentence containing 3 times the same word, such as "Foo Foo Foo bar".

To aovid this, check if the line is already "known" for a certain word before pushing it to the array:

```
foreach ($words AS $word){
   if (isset($result[$word])){
       if (!in_array($line, $result[$word])){
          $result[$word][] = $line;
       }
   }else
       $result[$word] = array($line);  
}
```

Comment: Wow that is so close, Thank You but i have some doubts :  When i test these text of lines : http://prntscr.com/7ybwpk   , got this output : http://prntscr.com/7ybx5u  this is the problem, dont know why it does not remove those last two lines.... and i dont want to delete the first unique line please see the edit(output) in my main post...will it delete those lines as well which contains capital and small letters?

Comment: @user3510922 yes, its case-sensitive. If you don't want that, simple make the key of the word-array upper or lower case. then `One` will equal `one`. Before adding it: `foreach ($words AS $word){ $word = strtolower($word) ....`

Comment: I am really not able to understand this logic(the last lines after isset), can you please explain in a simple short way... Thanks a lot : foreach ($lines AS $line){
   $words = explode(" ", $line);
   foreach ($words AS $word){
       if (isset($result[$word]))
           $result[$word][] = $line;
       else
           $result[$word] = array($line);  
   }
}

Comment: There i'm simply checking, if the array `result` already contains a key named `$word` or not. depending on that i'm creating an array, or appending to the existing array. I've modified the line to match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
#second 
while(!feof($fileA))
#should be
while(!feof($fileB))
```

and

```
if($c<3)
        fwrite($fileC, $line);
#should
if($c<3){
   fwrite($fileC, $line);
   continue 2;
}
```

but

> then compare that array which contains words of that line WITH all the words of next lines

makes only sence when you compare the file with itself!

EDIT:my post makes no sence at all, read note from prev post!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `array_intersect`?

```
php > $l1 = 'hello this is my word file and this is line number 1';
php > $l2 = 'hello this is second line and this is some text';
php > $a1 = explode(" ", $l1);
php > $a2 = explode(" ", $l2);
php > var_dump(array_intersect($a1, $a2));
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "this"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "and"
  [7]=>
  string(4) "this"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "line"
}


if (count of intersection >= 3) {
  skip line
}
```

Or am I reading your "matching" too loosely?